# <tr> border top working but not border bottom

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here's the issue. I have my code so that I should be seeing a border on top and bottom of each `<tr>` item. However, I only see what's on bottom except for the top element.

```
.tstyle1 {
    margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
    width: 950px;
}

.tstyle1 tr {
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}

.tstyle1 td {
    border: none;
}
```

Here's the issue recreated.
http://jsfiddle.net/fL3rx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

adding `display: block;` to your `.tstyle1 tr`

Comment: This is a bad idea, since the table row is a table row and not a block element. This can cause unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your border-bottom definition is simply covering your border-top definition. So the color beneath does not show. Try setting the `border-bottom:none` and you'll see the top border shows

The suggestion by @Pricey did some magic though.